# Pull data from FB app and store in spreadsheet

Tags: json, facebook

I am hoping you guys can help me out.  I play a Facebook game called Dragons of Atlantis.  It is a Real-Time Strategy game with a large world map.  The world map is a 750x750 grid.  I'd like to know the details of each coordinate of that grid, as unfortunately, there is no in-game way to view this data.  Not directly, at least...

There is a JSON file which supplies the app with partial amounts of map data (data correlating to a 20x20 grid on the world map).  I want to use that JSON file to store those results in a spreadsheet so I have my own record of map details I can view locally and on a whim.

Here is an example of one of the JSON files containing map data:
http://realm3.castle.wonderhill.com/api/map.json

I'll be the first to admit I hardly have any programming knowledge.  I'm a SQL expert, but that knowledge seems to be getting me absolutely no where in this endeavor...  :(

Any tools you guys know of which would help me achieve my ends?  I don't think what I'm asking for it all that uncommon or complicated, but I cannot find a solution for the life of me.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully the code below will get you started. Basically `$jsonurl` is the URL you want to call to get the map data. `$json` actually gets data. `$json_output` turns it into an array. You can then work with those arrays to insert that data into MySQL:

```
$jsonurl = "http://realm" . strval($realm['intRealmID']) . "." . $realm['strRealmServer'] .".castle.wonderhill.com/api/map.json?x=" . $x . "&y=" . $y . "%26timestamp=" . time() . "&_session_id=INSERTYOURSESSIONIDHERE5";
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);    
$json_output = json_decode($json,true);
```